# convert nested object to flat data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

Hi every one i have a data like this :
{
id: 1,
address: {id:100 , street: 'Kulas Light', suite: 'Apt. 556', city: 'Gwenborough', {…}},
company: {id:200,name: 'Romaguera-Crona', catchPhrase: 'Multi-layered client-server neural-net'},
email: "Sincere@april.biz",
}

i need too set value of id to address and company

how can i convert it to this :
{
id: 1,
address:100
company:200
email: "Sincere@april.biz",
}

```
  Object.entries(record)
     .filter((item) => typeof item[1] === "object")
     .forEach((items: any) => `${items[0]}:${items[1]?.id}`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `.filter`, you want the output object to have the same number of keys as the input object, so overwrite the key you're iterating over in the `forEach`.

```js
const record = {
  id: 1,
  address: {id:100 , street: 'Kulas Light', suite: 'Apt. 556', city: 'Gwenborough'},
  company: {id:200,name: 'Romaguera-Crona', catchPhrase: 'Multi-layered client-server neural-net'},
  email: "Sincere@april.biz",
};
Object.entries(record)
   .filter(entry => typeof entry[1] === "object")
   .forEach(([key, value]) => {
     record[key] = value.id;
   });
console.log(record);
```

A nicer way without mutating the existing object would be to use `Object.fromEntries` to transform the value part of each entry if necessary.

```js
const record = {
  id: 1,
  address: {id:100 , street: 'Kulas Light', suite: 'Apt. 556', city: 'Gwenborough'},
  company: {id:200,name: 'Romaguera-Crona', catchPhrase: 'Multi-layered client-server neural-net'},
  email: "Sincere@april.biz",
};
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(record)
    .map(([key, value]) => [
      key,
      typeof value === 'object' ? value.id : value
    ])
);
console.log(result);
```

`typeof null` gives `'object'` too, though - if that's a possibility, you can instead use for the value:

```
value?.id ?? value
```